# The sequence of destruction function of C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner for C++. I code the following two files and have some problems with the result.

.h

```
#include <string>
class StringTool
{

public:

StringTool(std::string name);
~StringTool();
void Print();
std::string getName();
void setName(std::string name);

private:

std::string name;
};
```

.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "StringTool.h"
using namespace std;

StringTool::StringTool(std::string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}

StringTool::~StringTool()
{
    cout<<"Delete: "<<name<<endl;
}

void StringTool::Print()
{
    cout<<"Print: "<<name<<endl;
}

int main() {

    StringTool tool = StringTool("Test");
    tool.Print();

    tool = StringTool("New Test");
    tool.Print();
}
```

The output is:

```
Delete: Test
Print: Test
Delete: New Test
Print: New Test
Delete: New Test
```

My question is:
1) Why it delete test at first and
2) Why delete New Test twice?

Thanks in advance. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Because you did not have a print statement in the constructor :-) 2) The "Nre Test" is deleted for `StringTool("New Test")` and `tool`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using implicit copy constructor. 
A new anonymous object is created, assigned to your variable tool and gets deleted
Then tool.Print() get executed.
again A new anonymous object is created, assigned to your variable tool and gets deleted and tool.Print() get executed.

to get desired results (as i understood) you must use

```
 StringTool tool("Test");
tool.Print();

 tool = StringTool("New Test");
 tool.Print();
```

that is use copy constructor (implicit) in second block

Answer (score 0):

As said by Jagannath, you should put a trace in ctor to help to understand what really happen, but also print the address of object.

Look at first line :

```
StringTool tool = StringTool("Test");
```

You first construct a temporary `StringTool` with `StringTool("Test")`, use implicit copy constructor to generate tool and delete the temporary object.

If you have wanted to avoid the temporary object, you should write instead :

```
String tool("Test");
```

that would use directly the constructor.

For second question (twice destruction for "New test"), you first delete the temporary object (like for first line) and then and the end of program `tool` is destroyed.

Comment: `StringTool tool = StringTool("Test");` is not assignment, it's copy initialization. And the copy will almost certainly be elided.